# .htpasswd not working properly, cancel = site appears

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

I'm trying to make .htpasswd to my /shop page in Wordpress. 
It's working, pop up with asking for  however when I click cancel then /shop appears anyway.
Here's my htaccess in main wordpress directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/shop require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile (mypath)
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

```
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile pathtoauth
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

SetEnvIf Request_URI .* noauth
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/shop !noauth
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/product-category !noauth
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/product !noauth

<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    <RequireAny>
        Require env noauth
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Satisfy any
    Require valid-user
    Allow from env=noauth
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
```

Last two lines were key. It was Wordpress.